# C# Finding duplicate properties inside a list of objects that contains another list

Tags: c#

I've got a list of objects, let's call the objects People.  Each person has a list of vacation days they've requested.  I'm trying to create a Linq query to find out how many people have requested the same vacation day.  I'm not having any luck.  Any advice, or perhaps a shove in the right direction?

Comment: any code would really help

Comment: Paste in your best effort thus far, maybe you are close.

Answer (score 1):

You could create classes like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public List<int> Vacations { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Vacation
{
    public List<string> People { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int PeopleCount => People?.Count ?? 0;    
}
```

and then get a list of people who have booked each day like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    var people = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { Name = "Person1", Vacations = new List<int>() { 1, 15, 200, 364 } },
        new Person() { Name = "Person2", Vacations = new List<int>() { 1, 15, 110, 210 } },
        new Person() { Name = "Person3", Vacations = new List<int>() { 1, 15, 200 , 210} }
    };

    var vacations =
        Enumerable.Range(0, 365)
        .Select(d => new Vacation()
        {
            Day = d,
            People = people.Where(p
                => p.Vacations.Contains(d)).Select(p => p.Name).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
    class Customer
    {
        List<Vacation> vacationDays {get; set;}
    }

    public class Vacation : IEquatable<Vacation>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int VacationId { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ID: " + VacationId + "   Name: " + Name;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            Vacation objAsVacation = obj as Vacation;
            if (objAsVacation == null) return false;
            else return Equals(objAsVacation);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return VacationId;
        }
        public bool Equals(Vacation other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.VacationId.Equals(other.VacationId));
        }
        // Should also override == and != operators.
    }
```

Now, you can use `SelectMany` here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2

More on `Contains` here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Start by flattening the list. This code will create a single, non-nested list containing one row for each person/date:

```
var flatList = people.SelectMany
(
    p => p.VacationDays.Select( d => new { Person = p, Date = d } )
);
```

Then you can filter any way you want quite trivially:

```
var lookFor = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2019");
var entriesForJan01 = flatList.Where( f => f.Date == lookFor );
```

Click this link for a [working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dicblV)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways using LINQ, but I would like to suggest a more efficient solution if you want to do the lookup for multiple dates. My solution uses a `Dictionary<DateTime,int>` which acts as a counter for the days we have encountered. Thanks to the fact that `Dictionary`  lookup is in constant time complexity (O(1)), this solution will be very efficient when you need to check the number of occurrences for multiple dates or even for all dates.

```
var dateOccurrences = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
foreach (var vacationDate in people.SelectMany(p => p.Vacations))
{
    //check if we already have this date in the dictionary
    if (!dateOccurrences.TryGetValue(vacationDate.Date, out int previousOccurrences))
    {
        //never seen before
        previousOccurrences = 0;                    
    }
    //add one occurrence
    dateOccurrences[vacationDate] = previousOccurrences + 1;
}
```

Now for lookup just use `TryGetValue` again. Alternatively, you can `foreach` over all the dictionary entries:

```
foreach (var pair in dateOccurrences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
}
```